# How to check consecutive cells in a column and check the difference between them in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to sort out a bunch of page numbers in this excel spreadsheet.

In the row, there are about 4000+ lines on page numbers, all following a pattern where they increase by one every [random number] of lines (could be 10 or 50 for example), apart from a weird mismatch in the pattern where a value 2 less than the value above it appears.

Screenshot:

[image]

I want to make a macro, possibly using RegEx in VBA Script to search through each value and check the difference between the value it's currently on and the value below. If the difference is one, then it's fine, but if the difference is two, it should delete that entire row the number that has a difference of two is on.

Basically, the script should delete the row containing the 2 in the image above.

I'm not too handy with VBA coding, so some help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Aydan.

Comment: Start with a loop through all rows (bottom to top!) with a check and a delete. Come back an we will help with problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your screenshot this code is assuming the column with the page numbers is going to be C.

```
Sub compareLines()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Activate

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    If ActiveCell.Value - ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value < 0 Then

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

    Else

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    End If

Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select first numeric value in a column and run this sub:

```
Public Sub removeValuesFromCurrentColumn()

    'select first number value and run script
    Dim rCurrentRange As Range, rNextRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rCurrentRange = Selection

    Do
        Set rNextRange = rCurrentRange.Offset(1, 0)
        'remove values which have relative difference less than -1
        If (rNextRange.Value - rCurrentRange.Value < -1) Then
            ws.Rows(rNextRange.Row).Delete
            Set rNextRange = rCurrentRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Set rCurrentRange = rNextRange
        End If
    Loop While (rNextRange.Value <> "")

End Sub
```